# ImportError: cannot import name 'ObsidianReader' from 'llama_index'

Tags: python, importerror, large-language-model, llama-index, obsidian

Trying to work with `ObsidianReader` from LlamaIndex, I've received an Import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ObsidianReader' from 'llama_index' (c:\Users\omer\anaconda3\envs\openai-env\lib\site-packages\llama_index\__init__.py)
```

I receive the same error when trying to install and import it on COLAB using the following commands from [LlamaIndex documentation](https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/data_connectors/ObsidianReaderDemo.html):

```
!pip install llama-index
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))
from llama_index import ObsidianReader, VectorStoreIndex
```

But it also game me the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```py
from llama_index.readers.obsidian import ObsidianReader
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `from llama_index.some_submodule import ObsidianReader`